# Use postfix to relay mail based on sender

Tags: email, postfix

I recieve mail from a server where I can specify *one* `.forward` mail where all mails get forwarded to. However, those mails have different senders, and one of them is important contact mail while the other is log mail. What I want to achieve is filter these messages and send them to two different domains.

In psuedo code:

```
if from == LOG_SENDER:
    forward_to("logs@mydomain.com")
else:
    forward_to("admin@mydomain.com")
```

Note that the original mal comes from **outside** my configuration reach. My current solution is having manual filters in thunderbird that just drop the logs in a seperate folder. But I would like to have the filtering as early as possible.

Is this possible with postfix?

My current setup is Postfix & Dovecot with SASL auth.

Comment: Have you looked at dovecot and sieve?

Comment: +1 for sieve suggestion

Comment: @NickW Could you create answer based on your comment?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it with Sieve, but if can be easily done with `procmail(1)` iff that's used as MDA

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip: I have added my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, since @NickW seems to unavailable, I will explain what I did based on his suggestion: I used sieve (already using dovecot 2) to create the filter I needed.

I actually moved from forwarding to sorting into a specific folder but alterting that in case I ever need something different is easy.

In the `protocol lda` section I add a line to active Sieve:

```
protocol lda {
  ...
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve
}
```

Then set the path for sieve scripts:

```
plugin {
    sieve = /etc/dovecot/sieve-scripts/%u.sieve
}
```

And the final script for my user:

```
require ["fileinto"];

if address :is "from" "logmail@example.com" {
    fileinto "Logs";
}
```

With these settings, all my mail gets sent into the `Logs` folder if it is from `logmail@example.com`. Very easy to set up once you figured out how to activate sieve (I find the documentation on that a bit lacking).

Comment: Sorry, on the weekends I'm usually nowhere near a computer ;) Glad you got it going!